# How can i install opencv in python3.7 on ubuntu?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I have a Nvidia Jetson tx2 with the orbitty shield on it. 
I got it from a friend who worked on it last year. It came with ubuntu 16.04. I updated everything on it and i installed the latest python3.7 and pip.

I tried checking the version of opencv to see what i have but when i do import cv2 it gives me :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Somehow besides python3.7 i have python2.7 and python3.5 installed. If i try to import cv2 on python2.7 and 3.5 it works, but in 3.7 it doesn't.

Can u tell me how can i install opencv in python3.7 and the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

Does `python-3.7 -m pip install opencv-python` work? You may have to change the `python-3.7` to whatever path/alias you use to open your own python 3.7.

Comment: when i use python-3.7 -m pip install opencv-python i get:                                    Collecting opencv-python
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv-python
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 19.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.  I did the upgrade days ago for pip it worked then now it gives an error.

Comment: Can i delete all the python versions and do a clean reinstall? will that help? and if so how can i do this